# Dynamically updated text in Graphics

Tags: manipulate, output-formatting

I created a Manipulate function that graphs a line along with its formula next to its graph.  But the formula doesn't display what I want.  As I use the controls sometimes I'll get the slope or the y-intercept in front on the text "f(x)=".  How can I fix this?

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[m x + b, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics[Text["f(x)=" m x + b, {3, b}]], 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]], {{m, 1, "m"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1, "b"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Unless you have made a typo in your cut and paste the error arises from multiplying `"f(x)="` by `m x + b`

Comment: Why bother with the `Show` expression when you can just add to the `Plot` expression the option `Epilog -> Text[...]`?

Comment: @murray   Thanks for the tip.  I will start doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Show[
  Plot[m x + b, {x, -10, 10},
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"],
  Graphics[
   Text["f(x) = " <> ToString@m <> " x " <> If[b < 0, "", "+ "] <> 
     ToString@b, {3, b}]],
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]},
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]],
 {{m, 1, "m"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1, "b"}, -10, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way, with a judicious use of [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html), that leaves out empty terms and puts them in (at least) traditional order depending on sign:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[m x + b, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics[Text[HoldForm@f[x] == m HoldForm@x + b, {3, b}]], 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]], {{m, 1, "m"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1, "b"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` does not really help when drawing **straight lines**.  If anything, it has a negative impact (albeit a negligible one in this and most cases).  It really only makes a difference, whether good or bad depends on the circumstances, when the plot is a curved line.

Answer (score 4):

In the post you have:

```
Text["f(x)=" m x + b, {3, b}]
```

which means `Times["f(x)=", m x + b]` whereas what you need is:

```
Text[f[x] == m x + b, {3,b}]
```

because `Text` displays expressions in `TraditionalForm` by default. So

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[m x + b, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
  Graphics[Text[f[x] == m x + b, {3, b}]], 
  GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 1], Range[-10, 10, 1]}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.04]], {{m, 1, "m"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1, "b"}, -10, 10, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

You may also prefer this

```
Text[PolynomialForm[f[x] == m x + b, TraditionalOrder -> False], {3,b}]
```

because it delivers consistent formatting across the value range, which I don't think the other methods do e.g.

[image]

[image]